# Storing connection string as named secret with Pomelo.EntityFramework.MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up an ASP .NET Core project with Entity Framework Core with a MySQL database that already has some tables in it. I'm using the [Pomelo.EntityFramework.MySql package](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) to connect to the database. Passing the connection string as a user-secret doesn't work.

I've set my connection string in user-secrets to `ConnectionStrings:Smokey = server=localhost;user=asp;password=password;database=data`
and then I run `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:Smokey "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql"`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("name=ConnectionStrings:Smokey", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("8.0.29-mysql"));
        }
    }
```

Running this yields `System.ArgumentException: Option 'name' not supported. at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnectionStringOption.GetOptionForKey(String key) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 940`

It works if I run it with the connection string directly in the source code.

How can I store the connection string/credentials separately from the codebase with EF Core MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it you don't even need to override `OnConfiguring` at all that was just something ef scaffold generated.

You can pass in a connection string during configuration like

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
        dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
            .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
```

You can use the IConfiguration object here to access user-secrets

```
var connectionString = new MySqlConnector.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        Server = "localhost",
        UserID = configuration["MySQLUser"],
        Password = configuration["MySQLPass"],
        Database = "data"
    }.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your post helped. Using this format resulted in the same Option 'name' not supported. protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseMySql("name=ConnectionStrings:uniAlias", Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("5.7.44-mysql"), x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1292) that was [fixed in 6.0.2](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/milestone/43?closed=1).

(As of the time of writing, I don't see 6.0.2 as an available [version on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) but I would expect it to be uploaded soon.)

Comment: Good spot. I'll try and use name option again once I see that reach NuGet